# Geodesic Dome defined parametrically

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric, geodesic

I've been researching for the calculus behind geodesic domes, and specifically calculus related to parametric surfaces. I've found [this](http://A%20geodesic%20is%20a%20locally%20length-minimizing%20curve.%20Equivalently,%20it%20is%20a%20path%20that%20a%20particle%20which%20is%20not%20accelerating%20would%20follow.%20Within%20each%20plane,%20the%20geodesic%20permutations%20are%20straight%20lines.%20Across%20the%20sphere,%20the%20geodesic%20permutations%20are%20large%20circles%20(like%20the%20equator).%20Whereas%20the%20geodesics%20within%20space%20depend%20on%20the%20Riemannian%20metric;%20and%20also%20affects%20the%20interpretations%20of%20distance%20and%20acceleration.%20%20%20Geodesics%20preserve%20a%20direction%20on%20a%20surface%20(Tietze%201965,%20pp.%2026-27)%20and%20have%20many%20other%20interesting%20properties.%20The%20to%20any%20point%20of%20a%20geodesic%20arc%20lies%20along%20the%20normal%20to%20a%20surface%20at%20that%20point%20(Weinstock%201974,%20p.%2065).%20%20%20Furthermore,%20no%20matter%20how%20a%20is%20distorted,%20an%20infinite%20number%20of%20closed%20geodesics%20exist%20on%20it.%20This%20general%20result,%20demonstrated%20in%20the%20early%201990s,%20extended%20earlier%20work%20by%20Birkhoff,%20who%20proved%20in%201917%20that%20there%20exists%20at%20least%20one%20closed%20geodesic%20on%20a%20distorted%20sphere,%20and%20Lyusternik%20and%20Schnirelmann,%20who%20proved%20in%201923%20that%20there%20exist%20at%20least%20three%20closed%20geodesics%20on%20such%20a%20sphere%20(Cipra%201993,%20p.%2028).%20%20%20For%20a%20surface%20defined%20parametrically%20by%20x%20=%20x(u,%20v),%20y%20=%20y(u,%20v),%20and%20z%20=%20z(u,%20v),%20the%20geodesic%20can%20be%20found%20by%20minimizing%20the%20arc%20length%20%20(formulas%20available%20in%20print%20form)%20%20A%20surface%20of%20revolution%20is%20a%20surface%20generated%20by%20rotating%20a%20two-dimensional%20curve%20about%20an%20axis.%20The%20resulting%20surface%20therefore%20always%20has%20azimuthal%20symmetry.%20Examples%20of%20surfaces%20of%20revolution%20include%20the%20apple,%20cone%20(excluding%20the%20base),%20conical%20frustum%20(excluding%20the%20ends),%20cylinder%20(excluding%20the%20ends),%20Darwin-de%20Sitter%20spheroid,%20Gabriel's%20horn,%20hyperboloid,%20lemon,%20oblate%20spheroid,%20paraboloid,%20prolate%20spheroid,%20pseudosphere,%20sphere,%20spheroid,%20and%20torus%20(and%20its%20generalization,%20the%20toroid).%20%20For%20a%20surface%20of%20revolution%20in%20which%20y%20=%20g(x)%20and%20is%20rotated%20about%20the%20x-axis%20so%20that%20t%20%20(formulas%20available%20in%20print%20form)), but unfortunately it comes short of providing me the most needed information, and so far I couldn't find the information anywhere else.

Basically, Yale says,

> For a surface defined parametrically by x = x(u, v), y = y(u, v), and z = z(u, v), the geodesic can be found by minimizing the arc length
>
> (formulas available in print form) ...
>
> For a surface of revolution in which y = g(x) and is rotated about the x-axis so that t
>
> (formulas available in print form)

Could someone please help me figure out what these "formulas available in print form" are? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you check your link please?

Comment: Your question is bettered answered by geometry.  Geodesics are unrelated to geodesic domes.

Comment: @VasilyMitch I'm sorry it didn't work the first time — here's the correct one: http://teachers.yale.edu/curriculum/viewer/new_haven_06.04.05_u#f